# SFML: waitEvent being called before pollEvent loop

Tags: c++, events, sfml

This is my code in the recent SFML 2.4.2

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My First SFML Game", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);

std::cout << "Press a key to continue" << std::endl;
int i = 0;
sf::Event event;

while(window.isOpen()) {

    while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
        std::cout << "Polling event" << std::endl;
        if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {

            window.close();
        }
    }

    if(window.waitEvent(event)) {
        if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)std::cout << "Event Activated" << i++ << std::endl;
    }
}
}
```

[image: Output]
All the event Activated output you see was printed when I clicked the close button and all the poll event was printed when I moved in or out of the window. It did not print Polled Event even when I clicked in the window! My problem is, pollEvents, why you no get called first and close the window when you get the close event first (apparently) because you have been written first? It does not make sense why the wait events method would be called first and pop the que. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no event, `pollEvent` will not return true and then it will not enter in your loop. But `waitEvent` stops the program until an event is received.

Read [the documentation of SFML Events](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Event.php#details):

> `sf::Window::waitEvent` - This function is blocking: if there's no pending event then it will wait until an event is received.
>   `sf::Window::pollEvent` - This function is not blocking: if there's no pending event then it will return false and leave *event* unmodified.

Comment: Is not the latest one 2.4.2? What can I do to ensure that the window is closed? There seems to be no problem here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blOBd49Io00 5:15. Why does it work here but not on my computer? There is clearly something wrong here.

Comment: How is the person in the video able to close his window by clicking the X button but not me?

Comment: Yes, 2.4.2 is the latest SFML release at the moment, but not the 2.0. I presume you forgot to add `window.close();` when you check your events after `window.waitEvent()`. You just print `Event Activated` and never tell the window to close. But It is really weir to use both poll and wait event, choose one that fits your desire.

Comment: I was following a tutorial, Look at my first comment.

Comment: on the tutorial, he clicks on the terminal red cross, not the application one because it wouldn't work. In the tutorial, he was just trying to show you that an event has been received but thats all. Take a look at this official tutorial instead https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/window-events.php

Comment: Oh sorry, it looks like I misunderstood.